# How to disable a button with a timed loop?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

i'm trying to disable a button for 6 seconds while in a loop but so far I can't quite figure it out.

```
var disabledStartTimer = setInterval(disabledTimer, 1000);

function disabledTimer() {
    var start = 0;
    if (start > 6) {
        clearInterval(disabledStartTimer);
        console.log("disabled timer stopped");
        attack.disabled = true;
    } else {
        attack.disabled = false;
        start++;
    };
}
```

attack = the button I click to attack.

Comment: What's the point of the loop?

Answer (score 2):

```
var start = 0;
if (start > 6){
```

Clearly this will always go into the else.  You set the variable to 0 and then test if it's greater than 6... it isn't.  You likely wanted this to be a global, move it outside of the function.